# Google Cloud Platform - RecognitionAudio not set

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-speech-api

since this morning, I'm receiving the following error from Google Cloud Platform when transcribing audio to text:

```
{ Error: RecognitionAudio not set.

    at Operation._unpackResponse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/longRunningCalls/longrunning.js:145:31)

    at noCallbackPromise.currentCallPromise_.then.responses (/usr/src/app/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/longRunningCalls/longrunning.js:131:18)

    at <anonymous> code: 3 }
```

Please note that I have not changed anything in my code, and this code was working perfectly before this. The code is as follows:

```
    const client = new speech.SpeechClient();
    client.longRunningRecognize({
      config: {
        encoding: "FLAC",
        enableWordTimeOffsets: true,
        languageCode: "en-US"
      },
      audio: {
        uri: "gs://some-cloud-bucket/audiofile.flac"
      }
    })
```

As you can see, for `RecognitionAudio` I'm sending a Google cloud URI as described in their docs here: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionAudio

I have confirmed that both the bucket and audiofile exist. Keep in mind this was working fine yesterday.

I have no clue where to look in order to solve this error. Cloud status says their platforms are up and running and are having no issues.

Any of you guys experiencing the same problem? Or am I simply doing something wrong all of a sudden? E.g. using something deprecated that was patched today?

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that'd be awesome. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Right. So 11 minutes after posting this issue the service started working again. ‍♂️

They have been down since (at least) `2019-09-18 08:21:01 UTC` which translates to about 7 hours.

For anyone reading this, the code above should be fine and working as intended.